# How to set min and max boundaries for a js variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vue.js, algolia

I am currently rendering a pagination with vuejs. This is for my algolia data.

I am checking if a user pressed on a previous button/next button or on a direct input(1,2,3, etc.)

```
    setPage: function(page) {
            if(page === 'previous') {
                // go back one page
                this.currentPage--;
                this.helper.setCurrentPage(this.currentPage).search();
            } else if(page === 'next') {
                // go forward one page
                this.currentPage++;
                this.helper.setCurrentPage(this.currentPage).search();
            } else {
                // change the currentPage with direct select(no prev/next button)
                this.helper.setCurrentPage(page).search();
            }

            // update the currentPage
            this.currentPage = this.helper.getCurrentPage();
        }
```

This works fine but I only have 0 - 4 pages(pages starts at 0). How can I make sure my currentPage var does not go in the negatives or beyond the maximum amount of pages that I have?

I guess using another if statement could work but it feels a bit sloppy. I am learning javascript and vue.js as we speak so I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: `if (page < MIN || page > MAX) throw new Error("That page does not exist!")`

Comment: depends on behavior wanted...are you wanting it to cycle to beginning when at end? Or hide button? Either way need to compare to total available somewhere and that isn't shown in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create methods that act like properties:

```
function nextPage(pageParam){
    if (page > MAX) {
        // Disable next btn enable prev btn
    } else { 
        // advance page 
    }
} 

function prevPage(pageParam){
    if (page =< 0 ) {
        // Disable prev btn enable next btn
    } else { 
        // go back a page 
    }

}
```

Wherever you call the decrimentor (this.currentPage--) you would call prevPage. This allow you to manage the behavior centrally. If for example you decided that you wanted it to carousel when you hit next on the last page it would go to the first page you can make it happen in a single place.

Comment: Thanks I like this approach. Pretty clean tucking all the messy code away in other functions and keeps the whole lot readable. Thanks for taking your time reading my problem!